# WCF System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wcf

I am getting exception with following message:

> Service 'ATPhoneControllerWinService.WCFService' has zero application (non-infrastructure) endpoints. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no service element matching the service name could be found in the configuration file, or because no endpoints were defined in the service element.

Service: App.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ATPhoneControllerWinService.WCFService">
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/ATPipe" 
                  binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                  contract="ATPhoneControllerWinService.IWCFService" 
        />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Client App.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint
         address  = "net.pipe://localhost/ATPipe"
         binding  = "netNamedPipeBinding"
         contract = "ATPhoneControllerWinService.IWCFService"
         />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Files are in different VS2012 projects (one is WPF and other is windows (not WCF) service). I am new in WCF and I don't know what I am missing.

Project Structure:

```xml
C:.
|   ATPhoneController.sln
|   tree.txt
|   
+---ATPhoneController
|   |   App.config <<<---<b>This is second App.config listed above</b>
|   |   App.xaml
|   |   App.xaml.cs
|   |   ATPhoneControllerUI.csproj
|   |   MainWindow.xaml
|   |   MainWindow.xaml.cs
|   |   
|   +---bin
|   |   +---Debug
|   |   |       App.config
|   |   |       ATPhoneController.exe
|   |   |       ATPhoneController.exe.config
|   |   |       ATPhoneController.pdb
|   |   |       ATPhoneController.vshost.exe
|   |   |       ATPhoneController.vshost.exe.config
|   |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.exe
|   |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.pdb
|   |   |       
|   |   \---Release
|   +---obj
|   |   \---Debug
|   |       |   App.g.cs
|   |       |   App.g.i.cs
|   |       |   ATPhoneController.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
|   |       |   ATPhoneController.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache
|   |       |   ATPhoneController.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
|   |       |   ATPhoneController.exe
|   |       |   ATPhoneController.g.resources
|   |       |   ATPhoneController.pdb
|   |       |   ATPhoneController.Properties.Resources.resources
|   |       |   ATPhoneControllerUI.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
|   |       |   ATPhoneControllerUI.csproj.GenerateResource.Cache
|   |       |   ATPhoneControllerUI.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
|   |       |   ATPhoneController_MarkupCompile.cache
|   |       |   ATPhoneController_MarkupCompile.i.cache
|   |       |   DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
|   |       |   MainWindow.baml
|   |       |   MainWindow.g.cs
|   |       |   MainWindow.g.i.cs
|   |       |   TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
|   |       |   TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
|   |       |   
|   |       \---TempPE
|   |               Properties.Resources.Designer.cs.dll
|   |               
|   +---Properties
|   |       AssemblyInfo.cs
|   |       Resources.Designer.cs
|   |       Resources.resx
|   |       Settings.Designer.cs
|   |       Settings.settings
|   |       
|   \---Service References
\---ATPhoneControllerWinService
    |   App.config <<<---<b>This is first App.config listed above</b>
    |   ATPhoneControllerWinService.csproj
    |   ATPhoneControllerWinService.csproj.user
    |   ATWinService.cs
    |   IWCFService.cs
    |   WCFService.cs
    |   WinServiceInstaller.cs
    |   
    +---bin
    |   +---Debug
    |   |       App.config
    |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.exe
    |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.exe.config
    |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.InstallLog
    |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.pdb
    |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.vshost.exe
    |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.vshost.exe.config
    |   |       ATPhoneControllerWinService.vshost.exe.manifest
    |   |       InstallUtil.InstallLog
    |   |       
    |   \---Release
    +---obj
    |   \---Debug
    |       |   ATPhoneControllerWinService.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
    |       |   ATPhoneControllerWinService.exe
    |       |   ATPhoneControllerWinService.pdb
    |       |   DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferences.cache
    |       |   DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferencesInput.cache
    |       |   TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
    |       |   TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
    |       |   
    |       \---TempPE
    +---Properties
    |       AssemblyInfo.cs
    |       
    \---Service References
```

Okay I am not getting exception now solved it with adding endpoints programmatically:

```cs
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFService), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/ATPipe"));
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWCFService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/ATPipe");
            host.Open();
```

Question remains where should I put xml configuration from app config file or what is wrong with the configuration above^?

Comment: Just a silly check: did you add the service configuration to an app.config of the project *hosting* the service (as opposed to the library with the service code)?

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do it?

Comment: Erhmm... I meant "did you - by *accident* - add the....". If you did you would get the error. If this doesn't make any sense it may help us help you if you expand on the final bit of your question: what is the exact project structure you have, and where doe the classes/configs live?

Comment: updated. the project's App.config hosting service contains that kind of configuration(<system.serviceModel>.. tags. Where should i put this conf then?

Comment: Looks fine like this at first sight. Have you looked at the "no service element matching the service name could be found" suggestion from the exception yet? What code do you have to instantiate the service?

Comment: suggestion sent me here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHInvalidOperation);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true just tells me that I don't have endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get it right is to use the [WCF configuration editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx) (comes with visual studio) to add an endpoint. 
Just define the endpoint and compare the resulting configuration with yours.

This way you do not have to bang your head by looking for spelling issues or misplaced definitions.